# How to change the data inside a tableview when pushing a button

Tags: objective-c, ios, tableview

I have a view with 3 buttons and a tableview. When I push button1, data behind button1 should be loaded into the tableview. But when I push button2, the data behind button2 should go into that same tableview.

How I can achieve that?

Answer (score 4):

Just switch the `dataSource` of the table view to a different object that conforms to `UITableViewDataSource`.

```
-(void)pressedButton1
{
    self.tableView.dataSource = self.button1DataSource;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


-(void)pressedButton2
{
    self.tableView.dataSource = self.button2Source;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: and what means self.button1 and self.button2 ?

Comment: he is trying to suggest dataSource associated with these buttons.